# Brake pedal travel adjustment after new brake lines?

Tags: brakes, hyundai, elantra, brake-lines

My 2014 Hyundai Elantra needed new brake lines, and now the pedal travel is a bit longer than it was. I don’t have specific measurements, and the brakes do work; it just feels like I have to push further to fully engage the brakes. Two things: is there a way to adjust this; and how difficult would it be? I wouldn’t have to bleed the brake lines, would I? I checked the brake fluid level, and it’s between min and max.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You never bled the brakes? That is a MUST whenever you break open the brake lines.

Comment: I didn’t do the work: a shop did. I assume they bled the system after replacing the rotted lines and refilling the fluid.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to assume they did, but it sounds like they've not done a "good enough" job. I'd take it back to them and tell them to complete the work. Tell them the brakes are mushy and it feels like they needed to be bled further.

Answer (score 0):

You have not completely bled the air out of your new lines.  Simply changing the lines will not have any effect on the pedal travel but air will.

I prefer to use a vacuum bleeder but you can also use the 2-person method.  Keep in mind that you have had the system entirely open and let a lot of air in.  It will take some time and effort to get it all out.

Comment: So, the bleeding is an iterative process? I’ve never done it, but I’m familiar with the concept.

Comment: It can take some time to work all the air bubbles out especially after replacing lines, a caliper, or the master cylinder.  Yes, keep bleeding until the pedal is firm.